# How to save a data retrieved from database into a string?

Tags: android

Is it possible to save a data retrieved from the database into a string?

For my case I want to save the TAG_NAME which is a data from the database into a string. Can I do it the same way as done for the Textview?

```
 // display product data in EditText
                txtwelcome.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));

                String name = (product.getString(TAG_NAME));
```

Comment: yes you can initialize it to a variable.if this is what you mean.

Comment: @adityavyas-lakhan sorry i can't remember as it is about a year ago

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan it didnt helped so i did not accept the answer... it was not solved , i just worked my way around the problem

Answer (score 1):

Its absolutely possible,as `product.getString(TAG_NAME)` always returns a string either empty or with value,you can store it in a String.

And even you can store any value from DB into String using `.toString()` extension

Answer (score 0):

try with the toString()

```
String name = (product.getString(TAG_NAME).toString());
```